# Why need of manual rollback in transaction management by JDBC?

Tags: database, transactions

This code I have taken from oracle site for transaction management. Why is manual rollback being done since the database will automatically rollback if the transaction fails?

```
public void updateCoffeeSales(HashMap<String, Integer> salesForWeek)
throws SQLException {

PreparedStatement updateSales = null;
PreparedStatement updateTotal = null;

String updateString =
    "update " + dbName + ".COFFEES " +
    "set SALES = ? where COF_NAME = ?";

String updateStatement =
    "update " + dbName + ".COFFEES " +
    "set TOTAL = TOTAL + ? " +
    "where COF_NAME = ?";

try {
    con.setAutoCommit(false);
    updateSales = con.prepareStatement(updateString);
    updateTotal = con.prepareStatement(updateStatement);

    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : salesForWeek.entrySet()) {
        updateSales.setInt(1, e.getValue().intValue());
        updateSales.setString(2, e.getKey());
        updateSales.executeUpdate();
        updateTotal.setInt(1, e.getValue().intValue());
        updateTotal.setString(2, e.getKey());
        updateTotal.executeUpdate();
        con.commit();
    }
} catch (SQLException e ) {
    JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(e);
    if (con != null) {
        try {
            System.err.print("Transaction is being rolled back");
            con.rollback();
        } catch(SQLException excep) {
            JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(excep);
        }
    }
} finally {
    if (updateSales != null) {
        updateSales.close();
    }
    if (updateTotal != null) {
        updateTotal.close();
    }
    con.setAutoCommit(true);
}
```

}

I have checked some other sites as well. There also manual rollback is being done. I am unable to understand this. Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing to recognize here is that *two* separate update statements are being done.  Most likely, the reason for using explicit transaction management is that the author of this code intends for both updates to have *atomically*.  That is, the intended logic is that both updates succeed, together, or both fail.  In the latter case, everything done for both updates should be rolled back, leaving the database in its original state.  So, while using an explicit transaction/rollback is not necessarily *required*, it is needed for the two updates to happen atomically.

Comment: @KishanKumar No, you have misread the OP's code.  _Before_ doing the updates, auto commit is set to _false_, meaning the OP can do an explicit rollback.  Setting auto commit to true at the end of the method is just best practice, to return the JDBC settings to what the default usually is.

Comment: I think autocommit is set to false because the author of the code wants to make both updates to take place or neither of them.

Comment: @KishanKumar Um...isn't that precisely what my answer already says?

Comment: Why he needs to handle manual rollback. Would not the database take care of this?

Comment: No, it wouldn't.  If auto commit is set to true, then each update would run inside a separate transaction.  So, it would be possible for the first update to succeed, while the second fails.  Then, the database might be left in an inconsistent state.

Comment: You are not getting my point. When he has already set autocommit to false then both updates are a single unit. So either they execute or not. So if they dont execute would not the database knowing that it is a transaction would rollback on its own.

Comment: No, that's now how JDBC works as it turns out.  If auto commit be set to false, then neither committing nor rolling back is automatic, both have to be done explicitly.

Comment: Oh! Is it so? Sorry then. I will read the documentation and then accept your answer. Thanks